# Haskell: FIFO queue algorithm complexity

Tags: algorithm, haskell

This is my attempt at a FIFO queue:

```
type Queue a = [a] -> [a]

empty :: Queue a
empty = id

remove :: Int -> Queue a -> ([a], Queue a)
remove n queue = (take n (queue []), (\x -> drop n (queue x)));

add :: [a] -> Queue a -> Queue a
add elems queue = (\x -> queue (elems ++ x))
```

`empty` creates an empty queue, `remove` takes the first `n` elements of the queue and returns the rest of the queue as the second element of the tuple, and `add` adds the list `elems` to the queue.

Will this add/remove 1 element in `O(1)` time and n elements in `O(n)` time?

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I don't understand how your code works. Could you add type signatures? What is the type of queue?

Comment: Why? `(++)` is not an O(1) operation, it's O(n), laziness notwithstanding.

Comment: @efie: I've added type signatures.

Comment: Unfortunately, `remove` may take up to O(N) time.  If a queue was created with N `add` operations, `remove` will need to evaluate N `++` operations to find the first element.

Comment: `remove` is not only ineffective on difference lists, it's also not particularly Haskell-idiomatic and often more cumbersome than the faster alternative: build up the FIFO _completely_ in one place in your program (the "source") apply `toList` to it just once (i.e. `$ []`) and pass the result _as a whole_ to the "consumer" function. Thanks to lazyness, this does not cause any need to finish the buildup process before you can start reading from the other end. The readout will automatically "wait" for the source to yield each element. Ideal behaviour for a FIFO, for many problems!

Comment: An O(1) FIFO in pure functional style is presented in the thesis paper "Purely Functional Data Structures" by Okasaki: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have implemented effectively amounts to [difference lists](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Difference_list). (See: [dlist](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dlist/).)

Difference lists allow for cheap appends, but unfortunately your removal will take linear time. It becomes more clear if we rewrite your code slightly:

```
type Queue a = [a] -> [a]

empty :: Queue a
empty = id

toList :: Queue a -> [a]
toList q = q []

fromList :: [a] -> Queue a
fromList = (++)

remove :: Int -> Queue a -> ([a], Queue a)
remove n q = (xs, fromList ys)
  where
    (xs, ys) = splitAt n (toList q)

add :: [a] -> Queue a -> Queue a
add xs q = (++ xs) . q
```

Note that I have made the conversion to and from lists a bit more explicit than it was in your code. You clearly see that the core of your removal code gets bracketed between `toList` and `fromList`.

Comment: What do you mean by linear time? Do you mean time proportional to the length of the queue? Because using your code I can remove from queues of infinite length in finite time.

Comment: Doesn't this `add` function adds elements to the start of the queue not the end?

Comment: @is7s Ah, you're right. So does the OP's code, doesn't it. I'll modify the code. :)

Comment: @Clinton going from a difference list to a list takes time linear in the number of elements, doesn't it?

Comment: @dblhelix: Yes, I'm not sure how that relates though.

Comment: @Clinton Re: removing from infinite queues in finite time: that of course depends on how your queue was constructed. Removing `remove n q` elements will incur the time it takes for the function `q` to produce its first `n` elements.

Answer (score 4):

Well, sidestepping your question somewhat, the classic purely functional implementation of a FIFO queue is as a pair of lists, one for the "front" and one for the "back."  You enqueue elements by adding them as the head of the back list, and dequeue by taking the head of the front list; if the front list is empty, you "rotate" the queue by reversing the back list and swapping that with the empty front list.  In code:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

data FIFO a = FIFO [a] [a]
              deriving Show

empty :: FIFO a
empty = FIFO [] []

isEmpty :: FIFO a -> Bool
isEmpty (FIFO [] []) = True
isEmpty _ = False

enqueue :: a -> FIFO a -> FIFO a
enqueue x (FIFO front back) = FIFO front (x:back)

-- | Remove the head off the queue.  My type's different from yours
-- because I use Maybe to handle the case where somebody tries to
-- dequeue off an empty FIFO.
dequeue :: FIFO a -> Maybe (a, FIFO a)
dequeue queue = case queue of
                  FIFO [] [] -> Nothing
                  FIFO (x:f) b -> Just (x, FIFO f b)
                  otherwise -> dequeue (rotate queue)
    where rotate (FIFO [] back) = FIFO (reverse back) []


-- | Elements exit the queue in the order they appear in the list.
fromList :: [a] -> FIFO a
fromList xs = FIFO xs []

-- | Elements appear in the result list in the order they exit the queue.
toList :: FIFO a -> [a]
toList = unfoldr dequeue
```

That's the classic implementation.  Now your operations can be written in terms of that:

```
-- | Enqueue multiple elements.  Elements exit the queue in the order
-- they appear in xs.
add :: [a] -> FIFO a -> FIFO a
add xs q = foldl' (flip enqueue) q xs
```

To write `remove` in terms of `dequeue`, you need to handle all of those intermediate FIFOs from the `(a, FIFO a)` result of `dequeue`.  One way to do that is to use the `State` monad:

```
import Control.Monad.State

-- | Remove n elements from the queue.  My result type is different
-- from yours, again, because I handle the empty FIFO case.  If you
-- try to remove too many elements, you get a bunch of Nothings at
-- the end of your list.
remove :: Int -> FIFO a -> ([Maybe a], FIFO a)
remove n q = runState (removeM n) q

-- | State monad action to dequeue n elements from the state queue.
removeM :: Int -> State (FIFO a) [Maybe a]
removeM n = replicateM n dequeueM

-- | State monad action to dequeue an element from the state queue.
dequeueM :: State (FIFO a) (Maybe a)
dequeueM = do q <- get
              case dequeue q of
                Just (x, q') -> put q' >> return (Just x)
                Nothing -> return Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a FIFO queue that's faster than taking a list and reversing it. Stefan's `add` isn't performant (O(n)), so here's what's worked for me after benchmarking:

```
add :: a -> Queue a -> Queue a
add x f = f . (x:)
```