# Tracing a tree?

Tags: haskell

I have a type for a tree like so:

```
data Tree a = EmptyTree | Tree a [Tree a] deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)

freeTree :: Tree Integer  
freeTree =  Tree 2 [Tree 5 [], Tree 6 [Tree 8 [], Tree 9 []], Tree 7 []]

main = print freeTree
```

What I am trying to do is to write a function that could be used say like so:

```
trace freeTree
```

And what a trace on this tree would return is: `[2],[2,5],[2,6],[2,7],[2,6,8],[2,6,9]`

Basically what it does is:

Keep a list of nodes already on the 'stack' (The root node at each depth that got us here). Every time you reach a new node, add a list which is the list of stack nodes ++ current_node to the result list.

Could anyone offer any advice on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry don't know the language. Seems like a data structure question though. Is this a binary tree? But seems like a tree traversal, with I am assuming 2 is a possible root. And you mean the stack as in push every parent node starting in at the root? so 2 -> 6 -> 8 would be one branch shown as [2, 6, 8] correct?

Comment: This looks as a breadth first search on trees.

Comment: @chi it is indeed that, but the tricky part is to trace back the route.

Comment: @KyleCalica-St Exactly this

Comment: It is a Tree, not necessarily binary

Comment: I don't know this language but I do similar things in C++. I would write out code to just do a breadth-level search popping each node into the stack as I go along it. Once you have that the stack should pop out the nodes starting with the root and then it's descendants. so [2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] is what im assuming the stack would like. would pop out just that. Do you have ability to know the depth of each node?

Comment: @Mio: what should one return if the tree has a depth of three? If you want a three-level array, I don't see much difference between a tree and a recursive list... Especially since the return type of the function is in the latter case undefined.

Comment: @CommuSoft The depth can be N, so the tree with one node per depth and 1 subtree per depth with 5 depths Tree 1 [Tree 2 [ Tree 3 [ Tree 4 Tree 5 [] ] ] ] ]  Would return: [1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5]

It is just BFS but at each node, you print the node and the parents.

Comment: @Mio: are you looking for a simple solution, or should it be extremely efficient? Is printing the elements in reverse order an option, because that's more efficient).

Comment: @CommuSoft The order is important, efficiency is not important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A first (not really efficient implementation):

```
trace :: Tree a -> [[a]]
trace t = trace' [([],t)] []

type Level a = [([a],Tree a)]

trace' :: Level a -> Level a -> [[a]]
trace' [] [] = []                                         -- current and next level empty? We're done!
trace' [] l = trace' l []                                 -- current level exhausted? Next level becomes current level and we construct a new level
trace' ((_,EmptyTree):ts) lu = trace' ts lu               -- currently an EmptyTree? Skip it
trace' ((h,Tree t c):ts) lu = ht : trace' ts (lu++el)     -- currently a tree? Enumerate and add childs
    where ht = h++[t]
          el = map (\x -> (ht,x)) c
```

The algorithm uses two `Level a`'s, the current level and the next level. You always iterate first over the current level and for each item in the current level, you add the childs of that level to the next level until the current level is exhausted. The only problem with this approach is that the `++` operations are quite expensive, especially since they are applied left associative and not right associative. One can make it a bit more memory efficient as well by using a more compact tuple list representation.

You can make it more efficient by using a **FIFO queue**, for instance [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11482019/67579) (let's assume at least the interface for all queues is the same, so in case you prefer another one, you can swap places).

In that case the code would read:

```
type Level a = [([a],Tree a)]
type LevelFiF a = FIFO ([a],Tree a)

trace' :: Level a -> LevelFiF a -> [[a]]
trace' [] ln | isEmpty ln = []
             | otherwise = trace' (toList ln) empty
trace' ((h,Tree t c):ts) ln = ht : trace' ts (foldl (flip enqueue) ln el)
    where ht = h++[t]
          el = map (\x -> (ht,x)) c
trace' (_:ts) ln = ht : trace' ts ln
```

You can probably make it more efficient using one of Haskell's monadic queues as well.

Answer (score 2):

We can think that we have a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) where each node marks a valid word, and then the job is to enlist the words:

```
trace :: Tree a -> [[a]]
trace (Tree a ts) = [a] : map (a:) (trace =<< ts)
trace Empty       = []

tree1 = Tree 1 [Tree 2 [ Tree 3 [ Tree 4 [Tree 5 [] ]]]]
tree2 = Tree 2 [Tree 5 [], Tree 6 [Tree 8 [], Tree 9 []], Tree 7 []]

-- trace tree1 = [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5]]
-- trace tree2 = [[2],[2,5],[2,6],[2,6,8],[2,6,9],[2,7]]
```

This is a depth-first solution that can be lazily processed with space required only for the current word. It doesn't return words in the exact same order you specified; if strict breadth-first order is critical, you should go for iterative deepening:

```
traceIDeep :: Tree a -> [[a]]
traceIDeep t = concat $ takeWhile (not . null) $ map (`lvl` t) [0..] 
  where
  lvl 0 (Tree a ts) = [[a]]
  lvl l (Tree a ts) = map (a:) (lvl (l - 1) =<< ts)
  lvl _ Empty       = []

-- Now we have bfs order:
-- trace tree2 = [[2],[2,5],[2,6],[2,7],[2,6,8],[2,6,9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to maintain state across recursive calls to `trace`. So consider a function signature like this:

```
-- First argument is the tree to trace
-- Second argument is the accumulated route
trace :: Tree a -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

With this structure you're effectively doing a depth-first search on this tree.

Comment: why the second argument `[a]`?

Comment: The second argument is the path that took you from the root to the current node of the tree. This trace function would process just one node and recurse for processing its children.